# Are there any methods to bypass Stored Procedures, Parameterized Query, ORM(Entity Framework) by SQL Injection in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

There'r many way to protect web app from **SQL Injection**, but is it 100% guarantee of quality? It seems to me that exists some methods for bypass these protections:for e.g. using comments, encoding, HTTP Parameter pollution maybe, i really don't know, can't find any examples for **ASP .NET Core 2.x**

code:

```
 public DataTable GetUserDetailsbyId_ParameterizedQuery(string registrationId)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            var connection = "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocaldb; Password=Pass$123;Database=AllSampleCode;Trusted_Connection=True;";

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                con.Open();
                var @query = "select * from Registration where RegistrationId=@RegistrationId";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegistrationId", registrationId);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.Fill(dt);
            }

            return dt;
        }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

     public DataTable GetUserDetailsbyId_StoreProcedure(string registrationId)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            var connection = "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocaldb; Password=Pass$123; Database=AllSampleCode;Trusted_Connection=True;";

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Usp_GetUserDetailsByRegistrationId", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegistrationId", registrationId);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter { SelectCommand = cmd };
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
            return dt;
        }
```